# git ignore specific directories exception

Tags: git, gitignore

I have source structure similar to this one:

- Project A

  - bin
  - src
  - ...
- Prjoject B

  - bin
  - src
  - ...
- ...

and I need to ignore everything except content of src folders. There are many other projects, and I don't want to put all of them into .gitignore. Sometimes I need to add another project into this structure, so everytime I add project, I would have to add it to gitignore...

So far I've been using * in .gitignore and manually adding files to be indexed using git add -f, but it is very slow method and sometimes I might miss something. And not seeing new files in git status is also very uncomfortable.

Is it possible to use something like this?

```
*
! */src/*
```

(I tried this one with several other variations, but it didn't work. I also tried using **.)

P.S: I'm currently using git 1.7.1

Comment: By way of clarification, using what you suggest *does* seem to work to the point where the contents of directories other than `src` are ignored. However, it does not seem to cause new untracked files within `src` to actually show as untracked files when using `git status`.

Comment: But if it won't show untracked files using `git status`, doesn't it mean it is still ignoring contents of src?

Comment: It seems so. I just wanted to clarify what you meant by "it didn't work", by providing a specific thing that did not operate as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your gitignore file [Bb]in/
This should ignore all your bin folders

And you can do the same for any other folder

Comment: I would like to avoid this. There are also other folders and files in some projects and adding all of them into gitignore would take more time than manually adding files to be indexed using `git add -f`. I want to specifically ignore everything except content of `src` directories.

Comment: You can just add only the folders you want to ignore, not all of them. [Bb]in ignores only the folders named Bin, not all folders.